# Intellij IDEA can't open form

Tags: java, forms, intellij-idea

Today I stumbled into an issue. Intellij IDEA could not open a form which was created some time ago using its designer. It showed the following error message: "Form file is invalid: null".
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the solution on the Internet, so I share my solution here. In my case I fixed the issue, opening the .form file in notepad and deleting all the Font tags like

<font style="1"/>

Hope it saves somebody else some time.